# MacOS/OSX - How can I run a terminal command and close the window while still have the process run?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

Where I would then be able to kill the running process with a `kill -9 <id>` command. It's annoying having a terminal window open that will run for a while.

Is there some command for this?

One that I could append to whatever command I'd like to run?

I feel like it's not an OS thing and more of a shell specific thing – where some shell command would include scripts that run in the background and others where they don't?

Comment: Try bg, it's a Linux/Unix thing, but should be available in osx. See if this works for you. https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ubg.htm

Comment: thanks @RudyM yeah it's built into MacOS, I also discovered `nohup`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep alive express process after close the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568135/keep-alive-express-process-after-close-the-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Restructured my questions and discovered the answer to my question in the suggested/related questions and discovered the `nohup` command and from the comments thanks to @RudyM the `bg` command